# Need to mask the account number with '*' using formula field

Tags: formula-field, string

I want to mask the account number field with '*' and want to show only the last 4 digits.

ex.
Acoount number - 12456665
Masked number - ****6665

The length of account number is not fixed. is it possible using formula field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this: `LPAD(RIGHT(AccountNumber, 4), LEN(AccountNumber), '*')`

RIGHT takes the last 4 characters from the account number

LPAD adds (AcocuntNumber character length - 4) '*' characters on the left of the string

Comment: Thanks. It worked